# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. -- For Loop

Tags: python, file

I've seen questions like this but mine is slightly different as I don't know where to indent because I'm using a 'for' loop instead of 'with'.

```
  f = open("Roll_List", "r+")
        for myline in f:
            print (myline)
            if CurrentUser in myline:
                x = myline.split()
                print (x[1])
                s = str(int(x[1]) + z)
                f.write(CurrentUser + " " + s)
                f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing f.close outside the for loop

```
f = open("Roll_List", "r+")
  for myline in f:
      print (myline)
      if CurrentUser in myline:
          x = myline.split()
          print (x[1])
          s = str(int(x[1]) + z)
          f.write(CurrentUser + " " + s)
  f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `with` statement to automatically close the file after you're done with it.

```
with open("Roll_List", "r+") as f:
    for myline in f:
        print(myline)
        if CurrentUser in myline:
            x = myline.split()
            print(x[1])
            s = str(int(x[1]) + z)
            f.write(CurrentUser + " " + s)
```